# Crashlytics add new applicationIdSuffix

Tags: android, crashlytics, fabric.io

I’m working on CI for android app and for those purpose I’ve created test app.

I’ve added Crashlytics support and a little bit later productFlavors to the app.

My initial package name was *‘com.kagarlickij.myapplication*’ ,

Flavours add *applicationIdSuffix* to the package name (http://prntscr.com/hm0u3s) and result is e.g. *‘com.kagarlickij.myapplication.**staging***’

If I build app with package name *‘com.kagarlickij.myapplication*’ it uploads to Crashlytics fine,

But if I build app with package name *‘com.kagarlickij.myapplication.**staging***’ new app doesn't appear in Crashlytics.

In both cases console output doesn't have any errors - http://prntscr.com/hm0svq

build.gradle (and the whole app) - https://github.com/kagarlickij/MyApplication/blob/dev/0.3.0/app/build.gradle

Why it goes like this and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer turned out to be very simple, but not very obvious - you have to run app built with new flavor in emulator at least once and will become available on Crashlytics - http://prntscr.com/hm25sa